# Update Table, Where Column Name is selected dynamically - DropDown.SelectedValue

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to Update Column of a Table where ColumnName will be DropDown.SelectedValue.

Example: A set of RECORDS will be displayed from a Customer Table where CUstNo ='1234' and  City= 'Chicago' and Grade ='B'

Once displayed I want to Update the grade to 'A' of all those customers from the above criteria.

In My case I have like 100 Columns, so in where Clause Column Names will be selected from a DaropDown.

In My Query, Update Customer SET ColumnName= 'some value' where ColumnName ='ActualValue'

So how can I pass the ColumnName which is Dropdown Selected Value.

I believe I can't give as 
Update Customer SET DropDown.SelectedValue = 'some value' where DropDown.SelectedValue ='ActualValue'

How can I resolve this ?...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it sounds like you want to build dynamic sql based on your grid? If that is the case you could always do something like

```
string updateStmt = String.Format("UPDATE Customer SET {0} = 'some value' WHERE...", dropDown.SelectedValue);
```

And then you could execute this statement. I don't really know exactly what you are using but there are far better ways of making db updates. You could use an ORM like [Linq to Sql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx) or you could even use something like a [SqlCommandBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.aspx)

**EDIT:** Here is an example in ASP.NET (although a winform app would be very similar)

Assume this dropdownlist is populated from some datasource

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" target="Default2.aspx">              
    <asp:DropDownList ID="test" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="test_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <asp:ListItem Value="" Selected="True"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Col1"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Col2"/>
        <asp:ListItem Value="Col3"/>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</form>
```

In the event handler build the updateStatement based on the selected column

```
protected void test_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string updateStatement = String.Format("UPDATE Customer SET {0} = 'some value' WHERE {0} = 'some other value'", test.SelectedValue);
    //execute the updatestatement;
}
```

The update statement string will look like this after the string is initialized(if Col1 is selected):

```
"UPDATE Customer SET Col1 = 'some value' WHERE Col1 = 'some other value'"
```

**EDIT 2:** Ok here is a sample in a winforms app

First i added a few values to the combobox. Next when my button on the form is clicked i take the selected value from the combo box and use it in the dynamic sql string. It will give you the same result as the asp.net solution above.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //add values to combobox from some datasource
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Col1");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Col2");
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Col3");
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string updateStatement = String.Format("UPDATE Customer SET {0} = 'some value' WHERE {0} = 'some other value'", comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        //execute the updatestatement;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.. My client is using .NET 2.0 so can't got for ORM. Well  in above snippet of code  SET {0} -- how can it know the columnName because ColumnName will be selected from DropDownList and even in where Clause how can I give the ColumnName.

Column Name will be dynamically selected by user from DropdownList..

Comment: Well it is tough to tell what your program looks like without seeing code, but I assume the values in the dropdownlist are column names, so when the user selects a value from the dll some event gets fired and in your event handler you can build the dynamic sql based on the value they selected in the drop down.

Comment: HI Thank you again for your response.  yes, that is true when I select value from ddl.... how can I build dynamic sql because in the dynamic SQL how should I give the columnName programatically ??

Comment: I went ahead and updated my answer with an example in ASP.NET

Comment: I want to Update in UpdateButton_Click Event handler... So I can use that snippet there.... I am using ComboBox {Winforms} so it doesn't have ListItem, I tried to use the ITEM property of it  but its not working for me.  I want to make it simpler, rather than taking the ColumnNam from ComboBox let me take some Label.Text value.... when I gave Label1.Text as ColumnName, SQL Exceltion is being thrown as it is it not being recognized.....

ANy alternative..... If I can pass atleast Label1.Text Value as ColumnName, that is good enough for me for now

Comment: Edited my answer for a winforms solution. Storing a value in a label doesn't really make sense, it would just be more complicated. If you are just storing strings in your combobox then you should be able to read the selected value on click of your button as I have shown above.